# Bio.Entrez.Parser.ValidationError: Failed to find tag 'Build' in the DTD

Tags: biopython

I just installed Biopython and wanted to try out its features and so I started to go through the tutorial.

However, when I reached the chapter about obtaining information from Entrez, I encountered a problem.

The example in the tutorial is simple:

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "A.N.Other@example.com"
handle = Entrez.einfo(db="pubmed")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
```

This works fine. But as soon as I want to parse a different database than pubmed I get following error:

```
Bio.Entrez.Parser.ValidationError: Failed to find tag 'Build' in the DTD. To skip all tags that are not represented in the DTD, please call Bio.Entrez.read or Bio.Entrez.parse with validate=False.
```

Trying the validate=False option also doesn't work, because this raises a Bio.Entrez.Parser.NotXMLError.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong and how can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get round this problem simply alter your call to `Entrez.read()` to include a validate parameter, like so:

```
record = Entrez.read(handle,validate=False)
```

The other answer to this question is right. It's a falt in Biopython parser. Hopefully they'll update soon.

Answer (score 2):

**THIS IS NOT REALLY A VALID SOLUTION, BUT SHOWS WHAT THE PROBLEM IS. I think it's probably a biopython (Entrez.Parse) bug, so I'll get in contact with them and see what they think.**

So a bit of hacking at Biopython shows the problem is because of a 'build' tag name.

If we do this manually, the first few lines of the `pubmed` XML request look like this

```
<eInfoResult>
  <DbInfo>
    <DbName>pubmed</DbName>
    <MenuName>PubMed</MenuName>
    <Description>PubMed bibliographic record</Description>
    <Count>22224084</Count>
    <LastUpdate>2012/10/30 03:30</LastUpdate>
    ....
```

But the protein request looks like this;

```
<eInfoResult>
  <DbInfo>
    <DbName>protein</DbName>
    <MenuName>Protein</MenuName>
    <Description>Protein sequence record</Description>
    <Build>Build121030-0741m.1</Build>                   <-------- THIS IS BAD
    <Count>59244879</Count>
    <LastUpdate>2012/10/30 18:39</LastUpdate>
```

I had a look at how the Entrez.Parser works, and it basically doesn't recognize the `build` tag. Further rooting shows that the tags are defined in DTD files, and einfo DTD file, which on my system is here;

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/Entrez/DTDs
```

If we examine the relevant file `eInfo_020511.dtd` and add a build tag line (the line below with the arrow wasn't there before);

```
<!--    
                This is the Current DTD for Entrez eInfo
$Id: eInfo_020511.dtd,v 1.1 2008-05-13 11:17:44 mdehoon Exp $
-->
<!-- ================================================================= -->

<!ELEMENT   DbName      (#PCDATA)>  <!-- \S+ -->
<!ELEMENT   Name        (#PCDATA)>  <!-- .+ -->
<!ELEMENT   FullName    (#PCDATA)>  <!-- .+ -->
<!ELEMENT   Description (#PCDATA)>  <!-- .+ -->
<!ELEMENT   Build       (#PCDATA)>  <!-- .+ -->     <------- I ADDED THIS LINE
<!ELEMENT   TermCount   (#PCDATA)>  <!-- \d+ -->
<!ELEMENT   Menu        (#PCDATA)>  <!-- .+ -->
```

It now works. The comments on this file suggest it hasn't been updated since 2008 (line below comes form the DTD header).

```
 $Id: eInfo_020511.dtd,v 1.1 2008-05-13 11:17:44 mdehoon Exp $
```

My guess is that the build tag has been added since then but this file was never updated to reflect that.